# How to set two different coordinates sytem for x and y axis in the matplotlib.pyplot.text() function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know that the positioning of the text with the `matplotlib.pyplot.text()` has a `transform` keyword used to set the text positionning in data or axis coordinates.

However, I would like to position the text in my plot using the data coordinates in x, AND the axis coordinates for y.

The reason is that if I change the view of my plot (change of x_axis and y_axis view limits), I would like that my text appears always at the same vertical position in my plot, while the horizontal positioning respects the data coordinate.

Is it possible to do it simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

```
ax.text(140, 0.8, "My Text", transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!